# How do I do anti-aliasing in java? (WITHOUT built in methods)

Tags: java, image, image-processing, geometry, antialiasing

I am going to try my best to give context for the below code. This is a method used to draw a circle and its center point in a 50x50 white square background. The following variables were used:

- xc,yx - the center coordinates used to compute the circle
- r - the radius of the circle
- STEP - how often a new point is drawn on the circumference of the circle
- x,y - the coordinates of each point that will make up the circle

Right now, my method uses a for loop to compute each points R,G, and B coordinates along the circumference of the circle based on the center point and the radius. What I am trying to do is anti-alias my output circle so that the round parts are not as jagged. However, I want to do this using only math and variables and I do not want to use any of Java's build in methods. Thank you to anyone who can help or point me in the right direction.

Below is my routine:

```
protected void proc_21() {
    info = "Draw anti-aliased circle";
    int xc = (int) rand(1, imgW - 2);
    int yc = (int) rand(1, imgH - 2);
    int r = (int) rand(4, 0.35f * (imgW + imgH));
    int STEP = (2 * (int) Math.PI * r) * 57;
    System.out.printf("circle centered at (%d,%d), radius = %d, draw in %d steps. \n", xc,yc,r,STEP);
    for (int i = 0; i < STEP; i++) {
        int x = (int) Math.round(xc + r * Math.cos(i));
        int y = (int) Math.round(yc + r * Math.sin(i));
        if (0 <= x && x < imgW) {
            if ( 0 <= y && y < imgH) {
                imgNew.setR(x, y, 0);
                imgNew.setG(x, y, 0);
                imgNew.setB(x, y, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    // set center to red
    imgNew.setR(xc, yc, 1);
    imgNew.setG(xc, yc, 0);
    imgNew.setB(xc, yc, 0);
}
```

Comment: FYI: It is generally much better / faster / easier to do everything you can do on the GPU / with a graphics library... But you're probably aware...

Comment: find a text book or online resources that cover anti-aliasing in theory. then implement it. research should be done by yourself. if you have problems implementing formulas you can ask here.

Comment: You're probably going to have a hard time adapting the algorithm you're using to add antialiasing. Instead of starting with an angle, and calculating the (x, y) coordinates, start with x and calculate y from that. You can do that for the first 45 degrees, and rotate/reflect to get the rest of the circle. You don't have to worry about skipping any pixels if the circle gets too large for the STEP size, and it's more efficient, since you're only calculating each pixel once (and it avoids trig functions).

Comment: [Wikipedia has an example in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) that shouldn't be hard to adapt to Java. Once you have that as a starting point, you can use a generalization of Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm to add antialiasing.